# Battery drain while doze, CPU abort wakeups

Tags: battery, android-11, wakelock, battery-history

I'm running Android 11, in a Moto G30.

I've noticed battery drains from 100% to 80% from 1am to 9am when I wake up. I decided to get a bugreport.zip using ADB and load it in Battery Historian.

Seems like at some point in the night, `JobScheduler` runs and finishes in a minute, but CPU stays on forever (even on full doze state). Reasons seem to be several `Abort:Pending Wakeup Sources` related to networking. At these point, battery discharge rate is ~2.5% per hour, whereas "normal" screen-off / doze rate is ~1.5%.

These are some screenshots, and here's the [bugreport.zip](https://mega.nz/file/aRkkFbTQ#wIHU-zgypxDsQgeeXEUX-_vAEbTShB7bcFuPoaSZM-4)

[image]

Here's the CPU wakeup sources list,
[image]

And here's a previous time when `JobScheduler` runs and CPU behaved well,

[image]

Comment: if you can renew the bugreport.zip download I'll have a look